# Pseudocode: Confusing syntax "<>" and "variable:2:6"

Tags: pseudocode

I am currently studying pseudo code, and despite my 3 year history in programming, this 1 particular practice-exam question has me perplexed with its unconventional code (shown below):

[image]

Highlighted in Pink, are my 2 main problems with the code. I have experience across 3 languages, yet I have never encountered the control flow method `<>`, and cannot imagine exactly what it would be used for. In addition to this, the variable `average` appears in the code in the form of "`average:6:2`", for which I am equally clueless.

To Summarise:

- What is the function of the control flow method "<>"
- As is stated in question (a) in the image above, what is the purpose of 'average:6:2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `<>` is common for `not equal`

   ```
   While number is not equal to 999
   ```
2. `number:filed_width:precision` is pascal formatter for real number with `filed_width` being the space for field and `precision` is numer of digits after dot. so `3.141519:4:1` will print `<space>3.1`

Answer (score -1):

What is the function of the control flow method "<>"
- It is "less than or greater than". If the input is equal to 999 then the loop ends. The number 999 is used as a [Sentinel Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

What is the purpose of 'average:6:2'?
- I'm thinking this is 6 digits with 2 decimal places.

Comment: <> means not equal to in several languages, such as Delphi, which is based on Pascal